# ROS 2 Bouncy : Node, Log and Classes best practice

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, logger, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am working with ROS 2 Bouncy and was wondering what is the best practice to log stuff in classes that are instantiated in a Node ?

I know it's now recommended to inherit the `rclcpp::Node` class and you can simply log by doing `RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "My message")`.

My question is about the best practice to log in customs classes inside the Node. For example, let's say we have this class :

```
class MyNodeClass : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyNodeClass()
  : Node("my_node_class") {
    CustomClass custom_class();
  }

  MyNodeClass::do_stuff(){
    custom_class.do_stuff();
  }
}
```

Which of this 4 options is the recommended way to give `CustomClass` access to the logger ?

Option 1 : We give the Node to the `CustomClass` constructor which save it in some var to be able to log in any function.

```
MyNodeClass : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyNodeClass()
  : Node("my_node_class") {
    CustomClass custom_class(this);
  }

  MyNodeClass::do_stuff(){
    custom_class.do_stuff();
  }
}
```

Option 2 : We give the logger to the `CustomClass` constructor which save it in some var to be able to use it in any function.

```
MyNodeClass : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyNodeClass()
  : Node("my_node_class") {
    CustomClass custom_class(this->get_logger());
  }

  MyNodeClass::do_stuff(){
    custom_class.do_stuff();
  }
}
```

Option 3 : We give the node to each `CustomClass` function if they need to log stuff.

```
class MyNodeClass : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyNodeClass()
  : Node("my_node_class") {
    CustomClass custom_class();
  }

  MyNodeClass::do_stuff(){
    custom_class.do_stuff(this);
  }
}
```

Option 4 : We only give the Node's logger to each `CustomClass` function.

```
class MyNodeClass : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyNodeClass()
  : Node("my_node_class") {
    CustomClass custom_class();
  }

  MyNodeClass::do_stuff(){
    custom_class.do_stuff(this->get_logger());
  }
}
```

Any other option ? Does any of this really matter or can we choose any option ?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304733/ros-2-bouncy-:-node,-log-and-classes-best-practice/) by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2018-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd actually recommend option 2 (passing the logger instance given by the node to your custom class), unless your class also needs the node, in which case option 1 is fine (no need to pass both the node and the logger).

If only a few methods of the custom class need to do logging you might consider option 3 or 4, but again I'd prefer option 4 to option 3, preferring to limit what information you pass into the class to only what you need.

In all cases, I'll point out that you can "extend" the logger given to the class to add extra namespace if you desire it, see: http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_logger.html#a68ab28459973c1072d3ad7a593ac994e

Also, you might consider taking a function for logging to completely decouple your custom class from ROS primitives altogether. For example:

```
MyNodeClass : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyNodeClass()
  : Node("my_node_class") {
    custom_class(
      [logger = this->get_logger()] (const std::string & msg) -> void {RCLCPP_INFO(logger, msg);}
    );
  }

  MyNodeClass::do_stuff(){
    custom_class.do_stuff();
  }

  CustomClass custom_class;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vadbut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39907/vadbut/) on 2019-02-26**:
For option 2, how do I declare and define the logger var on the CustomClass side?
I tried smth like this but it didn't work:

```
Class CustomClass{
  CustomClass(rclcpp::Logger &logger){
    this->logger = logger;
  }
  private:
    rclcpp::Logger *logger;
};
```

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-02-27**:
This:

```
struct CustomClass {
  CustomeClass(rclcpp::Logger logger) : logger_(logger) {}
private:
  rclcpp::Logger logger_;
};
```

Maybe?